# Limit of complex sequence: $z_n = \log(1/\sqrt{n})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have: $$z_n = \log(1/\sqrt{n}) = \log(1) - \log(\sqrt{n}) = -\log(\sqrt{n})) \rightarrow - \infty \text{  as  } n \rightarrow \infty$$

$$\text{Doesn't } z_n = \operatorname{Re}(z_n) \text{ here?}$$

Comment: It depends on the branch of the $\log$ you are using.